# OneToMany relation with nested ManyToOne relation returns broken relation entity

Tags: typeorm

I'm creating a structure where I have Repositories, Contributions and Users.

A repository has multiple contributions done by different users. It is important that I know the count property on the contribution.

But when I create a new Repository entity without connections I get weird behaviour.

[Example Code](https://github.com/Alfalfamale/TypeOrmIssue)

My `index.ts`:

```ts
import "reflect-metadata";
import {createConnection, getRepository} from "typeorm";
import {Repository} from "./entity/Repository";

createConnection().then(async connection => {

    const newRepo = new Repository();
    newRepo.name = 'test';
    newRepo.description = 'no contributions made';
    await connection.manager.save(newRepo);

    const RepoRepository = getRepository(Repository);
    const repos = await RepoRepository.find();

    console.log(repos);
    console.log(repos[0].contributions);

    await connection.manager.save(repos);

    connection.close();

}).catch(error => console.log(error));
```

my console output:

```console
repos [ Repository {
    name: 'test',
    description: 'no contributions made',
    contributions: [ [Contribution] ] } ]
contributions [ Contribution { count: null, user: null } ]
```

which is weird because I never created any contributions.

And the `connection.manager.save(repos);` call errors out on:

```shell
{ QueryFailedError: ER_BAD_NULL_ERROR: Column 'count' cannot be null
    at new QueryFailedError (D:\GitHub\Issue\src\error\QueryFailedError.ts:9:9)
    at Query.<anonymous> (D:\GitHub\Issue\src\driver\mysql\MysqlQueryRunner.ts:164:37)
    at Query.<anonymous> (D:\GitHub\Issue\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:502:10)
    at Query._callback (D:\GitHub\Issue\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:468:16)
    at Query.Sequence.end (D:\GitHub\Issue\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:83:24)
    at Query.ErrorPacket (D:\GitHub\Issue\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Query.js:90:8)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (D:\GitHub\Issue\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:278:23)
    at Parser.write (D:\GitHub\Issue\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:76:12)
    at Protocol.write (D:\GitHub\Issue\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:38:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (D:\GitHub\Issue\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:91:28)
  message: 'ER_BAD_NULL_ERROR: Column \'count\' cannot be null',
  code: 'ER_BAD_NULL_ERROR',
  errno: 1048,
  sqlMessage: 'Column \'count\' cannot be null',
  sqlState: '23000',
  index: 0,
  sql:
   'INSERT INTO `contribution`(`count`, `repositoryName`, `employeeGithub`) VALUES (NULL, \'test\', NULL)',
  name: 'QueryFailedError',
  query:
   'INSERT INTO `contribution`(`count`, `repositoryName`, `employeeGithub`) VALUES (?, ?, ?)',
  parameters: [ null, 'test', null ] }
```

My Entities:

```ts
@Entity()
export class Repository {

    @PrimaryColumn()
    name: string;

    @Column("text")
    description: string;

    @OneToMany(type => Contribution, contribution => contribution.repository, {eager: true, cascade: true})
    contributions: Contribution[];
}

@Entity()
export class Contribution{

    @ManyToOne(type => Repository, repository => repository.contributions, {primary: true})
    repository: Repository;

    @ManyToOne(type => User, user => user.contributions, {eager: true, cascade: true, primary: true})
    @JoinTable()
    user: User;

    @Column()
    count: number;
}

@Entity()
export class User{

    @PrimaryColumn()
    github: string;

    @OneToMany(type => Contribution, contribution => contribution.user)
    contributions: Contribution[];
}
```

What I tried:

Removing the `eager` on the ManyToOne from Contribution to User fixes the error and I correctly get an empty contributions array. But it isn't really a solution for the repositories that do have contributions.

The main question is: Am I doing it wrong or is this not something that works in typeorm?